# How can i debug this "Class 'App/Address' not found"?

Tags: laravel

I can not insert data in my table with migration
I have tried to put everywhere app/address, but this did not help me.
Can someone help me?
I want to know what is wrong here.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Address;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AddressController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail(1);
        $address = new Address(['name' => 'ginta latina 11']);
        $user->address()->save($address);
    }
}
```

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
>       Class 'App/Address' not found

Here is the model:

```php
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Address extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
}
```

and here is where I am using the class:

```php
public function address()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App/Address');
}
```

Comment: use `new \Address(['name'=>'ginta latina 11']);` and say resualt please

Comment: Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_PARSE)
syntax error, unexpected '/'

Comment: use \ ! use used / !

Comment: Questions you should ask yourself: Is my `class` located at `App\Address`? Is the `namespace` of my `Address` class `App`? Did I make a typo in my `namespace` or `class` name? What would help us is to update your question with the contents of you`Address` model and your file structure. Please provide this information so we could come up with a good solution.

Comment: Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Class 'Address' not found

Comment: here is the function that i used in user model
"public function address(){

        return $this->hasOne('App/Address');

    }"

Comment: and here is address model
"<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Address extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = [

        'name'

    ];
}"

Comment: Welcome to SO. I have added the relevant code from your comments to your question. In the future please can you edit your question with any new information rather than putting it in the comments as it will help you with getting a solution to your problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `hasOne('App/Address')` should be `hasOne('App\Address')` notice the `\` not the `/`.

This would mean your function would look like:

```php
public function address()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Address');
}
```

---

Alternatively, I would recommend using [::class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class) instead:

```php
public function address()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Address::class);
}
```

If the `Address` class is not in the same `namespace` as the class you're using it in then you will need to add `use App\Address;` as well.

Comment: @IonMîndru Glad I could help!

Comment: sorry, but i have another problem
I am new in laravel and now i have this bug
"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `addresses` (`name`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (ginta latina 11, 1, 2019-03-29 23:11:05, 2019-03-29 23:11:05))"

Comment: @IonMîndru It's saying that you're trying add `name` to the addresses table but the addresses table doesn't have a `column` called name.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 8.x,

> use App\Address;

is replaced with

> use App\Models\Address;